# Permutation and Combination 3

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Four different items have to be placed in
three different boxes. In how many ways
can it be done such that any box can have
any number of items?

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include any attempt you made to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each box is distinguished this can be done in $3^4$ ways as we have 3 choices for each item.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Item 1 can be in one of the 3 boxes. Same for item 2,3,4.